# Minificating and bundling SASS into minified css file with Webpack?

Tags: asp.net, webpack, sass, bundle, minify

Very, very new to webpack, but I'm trying to set it up to translate my typescript and my sass code and minify and bundle each into a single file apiece. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-compile-sass-files-in-visual-studio-and-webpack-6e45cdc1c14c/) but it didn't work in the end.

I got it to translat the typescript into js and minify it, but not the sass.
It will compile the sass in css, but I need it to be minified and this isn't doing that.

I'm making a ASP.NET app in visual studio. My webpack.config.js file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry:'./wwwroot/scripts/site.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/js'),
        filename: 'site.bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules: [{
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()]],
    }
}

module.exports = {
    entry:'./wwwroot/sass/site.scss',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/css'),
        filename: 'site.bundle.css'
    },
    module:{
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-laoder', 'sass-laoder']
        }]
    }
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.css']
    }
}
```

Comment: In this example you gave it is described exactly how to do it, even the whole code, read 5 times may help :)

Comment: webpack doesn't accept css as entry point, you should import your css into js